# Postgresql ERROR: hour "16" is invalid for the 12-hour clock

Tags: postgresql

I have `8/31/2020-16:29:31 PM` in the `submitted_date` column of my table.
and I tried to convert this to a timestamp using the `to_timestamp` function.

The command I am typing is:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(submitted_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY-HH24:MI:SS PM') from table;
```

and I get this error:

```
ERROR:  hour "16" is invalid for the 12-hour clock
HINT:  Use the 24-hour clock, or give an hour between 1 and 12.
```

I know this is very dumb. But what am I doing wrong here? I am out of wits trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Your format string is wrong, should be 'MM/DD/YYYY-HH24:MI:SS'
- `8/31/2020-16:29:31 PM` *is* invalid. `16:29` is `4:29 PM`, right?

```sql
select to_timestamp('8/31/2020-16:29:31 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY-HH24:MI:SS "PM"');
```

works just fine (with quoted PM in the format string).

Comment: Thanks! What is the use of the select you provided in the code section?

Comment: An illustration.